# Fatal Error Using PHP Autoloading

Tags: php, xampp, composer-php, autoload

When running a PHP file with autoloading I receive the following errors:

> Fatal error: Uncaught exception 'UnexpectedValueException' with
>   message 'The stream or file "app.log" could not be opened: failed to
>   open stream: Permission denied' in
>   /Users/name/Website2/BuildingWebsiteswithPHP2/vendor/monolog/monolog/src/Monolog/Handler/StreamHandler.php:87
>   Stack trace: #0
>   /Users/name/Website2/BuildingWebsiteswithPHP2/vendor/monolog/monolog/src/Monolog/Handler/AbstractProcessingHandler.php(37):
>   Monolog\Handler\StreamHandler->write(Array) #1
>   /Users/name/Website2/BuildingWebsiteswithPHP2/vendor/monolog/monolog/src/Monolog/Logger.php(289):
>   Monolog\Handler\AbstractProcessingHandler->handle(Array) #2
>   /Users/name/Website2/BuildingWebsiteswithPHP2/vendor/monolog/monolog/src/Monolog/Logger.php(341):
>   Monolog\Logger->addRecord(300, 'Foo', Array) #3
>   /Users/name/Website2/BuildingWebsiteswithPHP2/index.php(8):
>   Monolog\Logger->addWarning('Foo') #4 {main} thrown in
>   **/Users/name/Website2/BuildingWebsiteswithPHP2/vendor/monolog/monolog/src/Monolog/Handler/StreamHandler.php**
>   on line **87**

Here is my index.php file:

```
<?php 

require __DIR__ . '/vendor/autoload.php';

$log = new Monolog\Logger('name');
$log->pushHandler(new Monolog\Handler\StreamHandler('app.log', Monolog\Logger::WARNING));

$log->addWarning('Foo');

echo "Hello world!";
```

I have composer installed in my project folder, BuldingWebsiteswithPHP2. Will this instead need to be installed in XAMPP?

Comment: Change the permissions of the directories that say they have permissions denied.

Comment: @Ohgodwhy that worked! Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

The php process (usually the web server) doesn't have permission to access/write to app.log.